# LVM + Couldn't create temporary archive name

Tags: linux, rhel, lvm

we have 100% on /

```
Filesystem                Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg08_root   20G   20G  132K 100% /
```

so when I do lvextend we get the following errors

```
# lvextend -L+5G /dev/mapper/vg08_root
 Couldn't create temporary archive name.
 Volume group "vg00" metadata archive failed.
```

how to resolve this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You may be able to circumvent the space requirement for this operation by disabling the metadata backup with the `-A|--autobackup` option:

```
lvextend -An -L+5G /dev/mapper/vg08_root
```

If you do this, follow the operation with a `vgcfgbackup` to capture the new state.

**Post-mortem note:**

Since the ultimate goal was to expand the logical volume **and** resize the encapsulated filesystem, a one-step operation could have been used:

```
lvextend -An -L+5G --resizefs /dev/mapper/vg08_root
```

In this case, the filesystem type would have been automatically deduced, avoiding trying to use `resize2fs` in lieu of `xfs_growfs'.

Comment: I get -   WARNING: This metadata update is NOT backed up
  Logical volume lv_root successfully resized.

Comment: resize2fs  /dev/mapper/vg08_root
resize2fs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
resize2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open vg08_root

Comment: after that still 100% , maybe restart will resize it?

Comment: What kind of filesystem is contained within this logical volume?  Is it an `extN` type or is it `XFS`?  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305376/resize2fs-bad-magic-number-in-super-block-while-trying-to-open) for more information.

Comment: the file system is XFS

Comment: You need to grow the filesystem with: xfs_growfs /dev/mapper/vg08_root.  This isn't an `ext2|3|4` type filesystem, hence the bad superblock error.

Comment: excellent working like charm

Comment: Just wanted to say that this worked for my root filesystem/LV while the system was up and the root partition full. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

It is because there is no space in the `/etc/lvm/archive` or it is read only.

Judging with the partition being 100% full, `/etc/lvm/archive` has no space left. You will have to create some space in the root partition.

If it still does not work, means that the folder is read-only. Resolve using : `chmod a+r /etc/lvm/archive`

Comment: we do chmod a+r /etc/lvm/archive , but still the same error

Comment: no space left in root partition ...cleared some space and all worked 100%

Comment: I had a similar error, but in my case, my filesystem was out of inodes.  This answer worked, and I ran vgcfgbackup afterwords.